How to parse this sentence involving としてではなく?
Yet another question about 16 bit sensation chapter 3 column:

本作で『同級生』について書いているが、この大ヒットは、エロゲーから美少女ゲームへの転換を大きく進めたと言える。それはつまり、「エロがメインで、そのための存在としてのヒロイン」から、「ヒロインと主人公との関係性や感情、物語を紡ぐことによってたどり着く恋愛描写、そしてエロ」とゲーム内の序列が転換したことに他ならない。つまりヒロインはエロの道具(失礼)ではなく、恋愛対象でドラマの主人公となり、その結果として、より深いキャラクター性を持つことになる。それが何を生んだか一一一ヒロインがよりかわいくなったのだ。これが後の「萌え」につながっていくのは、想像に難くないだろう。そしてそうした作品の多くは「エロの舞台」としてではなく、ヒロインをより魅力的に描くために18禁である必要があり、エロシーンもそのひとつであるというものだった。

I need help making sense of the last sentence. It seems like the reason for 18禁である必要があり is not 「エロの舞台」として but ヒロインをより魅力的に描く right? Also, I wonder what そのひとつ refers to here.


the reason for 18禁である必要があり is not 「エロの舞台」として but ヒロインをより魅力的に描く right?

Yes. The games needed to be 18-rated not because it's intended as エロの舞台 but because they wanted to portray their heroines attractively.

I wonder what そのひとつ refers to here.

It means erotic scenes were one of the ways to portray attractive heroines.
